# if or/and else if statement being passed over

Tags: ios, swift, if-statement

I'm building a custom parse login for my app and I'm having trouble getting one of my if statements in my loginBTN Action to execute.  Once I press login with the `loginSwitch.on == true` even when my username and password text fields are empty/nil it segues to the profile view i.e. opens the app with the last logged user.  In my code I'm trying to get it to display an alert asking for username and password to be entered.  What's more confusing is that when the `else if loginSwitch.on == false` is called and the 3 textfields are empty I'm getting my alert message.  Please help stop the automatic segue in the "LOGIN" state / loginSwitch.on == true.

```
 @IBAction func loginBTN(sender: AnyObject)
    {
        if loginSwitch.on == true
        {
            if usernameTXTFLD != nil || passwordTXTFLD != nil
            {
                PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground(usernameTXTFLD.text!, password:passwordTXTFLD.text!) {
                    (user: PFUser?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                    if user == user
                    {
                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("loginToProfileSegue", sender: self)
                        })
                    } else {
                        let errorString = error!.userInfo["error"] as? String
                        self.displayAlert("Log In Failed", message: errorString!)
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                self.displayAlert("Log In Failed", message: "Error: Please Provide Unique Username and Password")
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if self.usernameTXTFLD != nil || self.passwordTXTFLD != nil || self.emailTXTFLD != nil
            {
                let user = PFUser()
                user.username = usernameTXTFLD.text
                user.password = passwordTXTFLD.text
                user.email = emailTXTFLD.text
                user.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock {
                    (succeeded: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                    if let _ = error
                    {
                        self.displayAlert("Log In Failed", message: "Error: Please Provide Unique Username, Password, and Email Address")
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("loginToProfileSegue", sender: self)
                        })
                    }
                }

            }
            else if usernameTXTFLD == nil || passwordTXTFLD == nil || emailTXTFLD == nil
            {
                //Alert - Please provide username, password, and emailaddress
                self.displayAlert("Signup Failed", message: "Error: Please Provide Unique Username, Password, and Email Address")
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: how did you connect your segue? did you drag it from your button or from your ViewContorller ?

Comment: I drugged from view controller. I'm also using the segue for a twitter and facebook login and they work as expected. Do you suggest just making 1 unique segue for this particular button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few issues. Several of your `nil` checks are incorrect and you are checking if the text field itself is `nil` instead of checking if there is any text in the text field.

```
if loginSwitch.on == true
{
    if usernameTXTFLD.text!.isEmpty == false && passwordTXTFLD.text!.isEmpty == false
    {
        PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground(usernameTXTFLD.text!, password:passwordTXTFLD.text!) {
            (user: PFUser?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if user == user
            {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("loginToProfileSegue", sender: self)
                })
            } else {
                let errorString = error!.userInfo["error"] as? String
                self.displayAlert("Log In Failed", message: errorString!)
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        self.displayAlert("Log In Failed", message: "Error: Please Provide Unique Username and Password")
    }
}
else
{
    if self.usernameTXTFLD.text!.isEmpty == false && self.passwordTXTFLD.text!.isEmpty == false && self.emailTXTFLD.text!.isEmpty == false
    {
        let user = PFUser()
        user.username = usernameTXTFLD.text
        user.password = passwordTXTFLD.text
        user.email = emailTXTFLD.text
        user.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (succeeded: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if let _ = error
            {
                self.displayAlert("Log In Failed", message: "Error: Please Provide Unique Username, Password, and Email Address")
            }
            else
            {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("loginToProfileSegue", sender: self)
                })
            }
        }

    }
    else
    {
        //Alert - Please provide username, password, and emailaddress
        self.displayAlert("Signup Failed", message: "Error: Please Provide Unique Username, Password, and Email Address")
    }
}
```

Comment: It's telling me that type "String" has no member "length", Is there a better way to determine length or characters?

Comment: cast it to the NSString, or you could also use ```text?.characters.count > 1```

Comment: That was my Objective-C showing. See my update. I think that will work.

Comment: It worked.  You were right about the `?` and`!`s though.  Here's what I had to use....`if usernameTXTFLD.text!.isEmpty == false && passwordTXTFLD.text!.isEmpty == false`  Thank you.